# How to update existing JSON with a smaller subset JSON in Ansible?

Tags: json, ansible

I have this task:

```
- name: Get Status page url
      uri:
        url: "{{ responseversion.json.results[0]._links.self }}?expand=version,body.storage"
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
        force_basic_auth: yes

        headers:
          Authorization: Basic blablab
      register: responseurl

    - name: print body without updates
      debug: var=responseurl


    - debug:
        msg: "{{ responseurl | combine({'json':{'body':{ 'version':{'minorEdit':true, 'number':responseversion.json.results[0].version.number+1} }}}) }}"
```

Basically I get a response, get the page "version" and "minorEdit" keys from response and replace them and their values in the original response. There are other keys besides "version", I need to keep them also, as well as the neighboring keys inside "version" key.
The targeted "version" key before update looks like this:

```
"version": {
                "_expandable": {
                    "content": "/rest/api/content/164794022"
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": "https://hostname.com/confluence/rest/experimental/content/164794022/version/4"
                },
                "by": {
                    "_expandable": {
                        "status": ""
                    },
                    "_links": {
                        "self": "https://hostname.com/confluence/rest/api/user?key=ff80808164c5cf240164c6e351d30002"
                    },
                    "displayName": "my name",
                    "profilePicture": {
                        "height": 48,
                        "isDefault": false,
                        "path": "/confluence/download/attachments/98107443/user-avatar",
                        "width": 48
                    },
                    "type": "known",
                    "userKey": "ff80808164c5cf240164c6e351d30002",
                    "username": "my name"
                },
                "hidden": false,
                "message": "",
                "minorEdit": false,
                "number": 4,
                "when": "2021-08-25T15:36:35.285+03:00"
            }
```

The final debug task print the version key like this:

```
"json": {
            "body": {
                "version": {
                    "minorEdit": true,
                    "number": 5
                }
            }
        }
```

You can see the JSON for replacement inline, inside the "combine" function call. Whole JSON key gets overriden.

Comment: Edited with all info needed. I am getting info from confluence page, to update the same confluence page with new data.